# Cassandra TimeOut?

Tags: cassandra, timeout, cqlsh

I have a large dataset in a single table (over 2 million rows, each with over 100 columns), stored in cassandra, a few months ago  (2 maybe?) I was able to execute a simple command to keep track of the amount of records in that table:

```
SELECT count(*) from mydata limit 11111111;
```

A few days ago I tried the same command and got the following error:

```
errors={}, last_host=168.176.61.25
```

The error itself does not say much, After some research on google I think it might be related to a timeout. As you might expect shorter running queries execute properly, and the error appears always after some 10 seconds of processing.

A far as I understand, the timeouts for cassandra are set in cassandra.yaml, I have changed the following values

read_request_timeout_in_ms: 25000

range_request_timeout_in_ms: 25000

request_timeout_in_ms: 25000

However there is no change at all on the error and it still fails after the same 10 seconds,

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Fuanka

Comment: Well, design for your query. If this count is something you need to run all the time, keep a table of counters and update it when you add or delete rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the to count how many records, don't use count(*), put a counter column in your schema: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

if you also need to get all the data for other operation, there are multiple reseasons of this timeout, I can provide you with some if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, 
That looks like an easier solution. I'm no longer working on that particular dataset. However I would definitively like to know how to handle that many rows and avoid the timeout. Could you give some hints?.

Thanks a lot Manhal

Comment: you need to get the result paged, cassandra support limit but does not support offset.
if you are doing direct cql, use timeuuid in order to overcome the offset issue.
if you are using the driver, use the driver pagination